# Upload 95 GB CSV file into MySQL MyISAM table via Load data infile: CSV engine an alternative?

Tags: file-upload, import, mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to upload a 95 GB [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file into a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database (MySQL 5.1.36) via the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE MOD13Q1 (
rid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
gid MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
yr SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
dyyr SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
ndvi DECIMAL(7,4) NOT NULL comment 'NA value is 9',
reliability TINYINT(4)  NOT NULL comment 'NA value is 9',
ndviquality1 TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
ndviquality2 TINYINT(1) NOT NULL ,
primary key (rid),
key(gid)
) ENGINE = MyISAM ;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'datafile.csv' INTO TABLE MOD13Q1 FIELDS TERMINATED by ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(gid, yr, dyyr, ndvi, reliability,
ndviquality1, ndviquality2
) ;
```

I'm running this script via DOS at the moment, but the database is not responding. It works for smaller CSV files (1.5 GB) fine. Would it work for this file size?

Do you have any recommendation on how to do this more efficiently/faster? Would engine = CSV be an alternative (indexing not activated! -> so queries might run super slow?).

**Update**

Thanks for the tips, It worked!

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\\AAJan\\data\\data.csv' INTO TABL
E MOD13Q1
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
    ->     LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    ->     IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->     (gid, yr, dyyr, ndvi, reliability,
    ->     ndviquality1, ndviquality2
    ->     ) ;
Query OK, -1923241485 rows affected (18 hours 28 min 51.26 sec)
Records: -1923241485  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Hope this is helpful for others avoiding splitting data up in chunks.

Comment: @Mark: tokyo cabinet is key/value DBM so nothing to do IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable all the constraints when you are importing. Apart from that I think it should work properly and to be noted that it is going to take a while, probably hours.

Answer (score 3):

No easy way, you will have to split your data in chunks and then import those...

Answer (score 0):

Bcp ? ..................................
Oh wait. It does not matter anyway it will be some bulk transaction. You need chunks. You need it to avoid overfilling yout log segment space. The lock count limits. Anything greater than 1 million of things at a time it too much. So the best known batch size for BCP is 10,000 records!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with RageZ and Sarfraz answers, but i have something to add.

**1. Increasing database cache and reconfiguring some mysql options may help (RAM usage).**

Take a look at this:

[Mysql Database Performance tuning](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mysqlperformance.htm)

I think you should focus on `write_buffer`, `read_buffer`, `query_cache_size` and other RAM and I/O related options.

**2. You probably need faster storage device. What are you using now?**

For database big like this - you should use RAID-5 array with fast and modern hard disks.

Maybe your configuration is enough for everyday tasks, but what about backups and crysis situations?

Creating backup and restoring database big like this will take too much time on machine, that needs 18 hours for simple insert import.

I know that 95GB is really big text file, but... i think you should use hardware that is able to do simple operations like this in max 2-3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [MySQLTuner](http://mysqltuner.pl) - High Performance MySQL Tuning Script written in perl which helps you with your MySQL configuration and make recommendations for increased performance and stability.